# Bellman equation for MRP?

Tags: return-value, reinforcement-learning

In the Bellman equation for MRP, I cannot understand why:

```
expectation[ G_(t+1) | s_t = s] = expectation[ expectation[ G_(t+1) | s_(t+1)] | s_t = s].
```

How should I understand this?

[bellman equatin for MRP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6fW3.png)

Equations of the process of transformation.